# why include a for loop inside a for loop

Tags: c

i have seen some code where programmers include a for loop inside a for loop.for example

```
for(i=0; i<n; i++){
for(j=0;j<n;j++)
```

Why is this important?
Please tell me when do I need to include this nested loop in my code.

Comment: Do you know Matrix.....? ... Not the movie....

Comment: @LPs, mentioned that in my example, but he seems way too new to programming. He probably knows Neo better.

Comment: @user5921769 Try to understand the following [Program](http://ideone.com/JP1UmO)

Comment: Yeah - 'Matrix' the movie was a 3D maze and would need a loop within a loop within a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont use nested loops because they are important. You use it because the program requires it. Try to understand the logic of the program you are referring. Then you will understand why they are used. You can read about nested loops [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_nested_loops.htm).

Answer (score 0):

It is NOT important. You simply use nested for loops when you feel you need to. Some good examples would be sorting algorithms. You can't sort an entire vector in one loop, so you need a nested loop to ensure that you sort the entire vector, not just the elements from the first iteration.

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm) is a list with some sorting algorithms. Take a look at how they use nested for loops to see why it is sometimes required.

Another good example of when to use nested loops is when you need to iterate through a matrix. A single for loop would let you check only the first line from the matrix, so you add a secondary loop to iterate through every single line, not just one.

Answer (score 0):

It is not important to use nested loop in every program. It depends upon the requirement of the program.

You can understand the concept of nested programming [HERE](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/a-nested-loop-puzzle/)